# JSON.Net serialize XML to JSON camel case

Tags: formatting, xml-serialization, json.net

How do I get JSON.Net to serialize my XML to camel case JSON and without the "@"?

this is what I currently have but it prepends @ to the properties and does not camel case...

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myXmlString);

string jsonText = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Make a model of your XML data

example

```
public class MyClass
    {
        [JsonProperty("@SomeXMLProperty")]
        public string MyString{ get; set; }
    }
```

then deserialize XML to your model

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xmlDocument);
var myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonData);
```

then just use **CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver** and **Formatting.Indented**

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject,
                              Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
                              new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
```

**UPDATE:**

The first solution is simple and clean (no need to write custom resolvers etc.) this is just for removing @ sign

```
  var xml = new XmlDocument();
  xml.XmlResolver = null;        
  xml.Load("yourfilehere");

  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

  var withoutATSign = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(json, "(?<=\")(@)(?!.*\":\\s )", String.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If anybody knows a better solution for both cases then the first it would be nice to look at it.

*WebAPI addition*

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented; 
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Comment: are you saying to Serialize then Deserialize then Serialize again?

Comment: Yes the first solution is the cleanest. Are you maybe using WebAPI and in need of the camel case? If so, then it's just two lines.